# Move a given volume (size) of files

Tags: batch-file, size, move

Need to move any given quantity of files from a given type (csv in example) from ./source to a ./target folder and that:

- the total size of all files moved is below a given value SrcMax
- files are moved as a pair, so "twin" stay together

the code so far, that moves all files, or doesn't anything at all

```
set DataLoc=d:\target
Set HoldLoc=d:\source

set SrcCount=0
set SrcSize=0

REM Set 2MB total volume to move
set SrcMax=2000000

FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %%a IN ('dir /A-D /O-D /B "%HoldLoc%"\*.csv') DO (
        SET /A SrcCount += 1 
        SET /A SrcSize+=%%~za
        oddn=%SrcCount% %% 2
        if !SrcSize! LEQ %SrcMax% && !oddn!==0 (
        MOVE /y "%HoldLoc%\%%a" "%DataLoc%"
        )
    )
```

EDIT 1:
this Batch to move files based on total size provides some guidance, but still missing something

adding more information:

file on source folder are like this:

d:\source\base1-yyyymmddhhmm-data.csv  (less than 100 MB)

d:\source\base1-yyyymmddhhmm-flag.csv  (less than 200 KB)

d:\source\base2-yyyymmddhhmm-data.csv

d:\source\base2-yyyymmddhhmm-flag.csv

...

target folder is empty

The requirement is to move the "data" and respective "flag" files together.
They are created with the same "date modified", so the loop can be run based on this date, and all files will be shorted properly as a pair.
The "flag" file is really small when compared with the "data".

the issue seems to be how the loop accumulates the file size to compare with the SrcMax.

corrected the :

> !SrcSize!
> LEQ %SrcMax%

(instead of SrcCount).

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add more information. How are the pairs of files related? Or is the requirement only to move an equal number of unrelated files? Do you mean `if !SrcSize! LEQ %SrcMax%` (instead of `SrcCount`). Add example directory listings of `d:\source` and `d:\target` before and after running your script and show the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

This is working for now, except the counter to ensure that "twin" files are moved together.

```
set DataLoc=d:\target
Set HoldLoc=d:\source

set SrcCount=0
set SrcSize=0

REM Set 2MB total volume to move
set SrcMax=2000000

FOR /F TOKENS^=* %%a IN ('dir /A-D /O-D /B "%HoldLoc%"\*.csv') DO (
    SET /A SrcCount += 1 
    SET /A "SrcSize+=%%~za"
    if !SrcSize! LEQ %SrcMax% (
        MOVE /y "%HoldLoc%\%%~nxa" "%DataLoc%")
    )
```

ISSUE: when move the .bat file to another location, maintaining the same code, it stops working. Why?